# Setting Image Transparency

Tags: asp.net, html, image

i am having the source code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="condition.aspx.cs" Inherits="condition" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<p>
    <br />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="234px" 
        ImageUrl="~/images/condition.jpeg" Width="289px" />

</p>

<p style="font-size: small">
    Very often there are health issues that cannot be clearly classified under a 
    specific medical specialty. The topics under this section include health issues 
    of this kind. This section also explains symptoms related to different kinds of 
    illnesses and diseases. The different medical specialties are also covered in 
    this section.</p>
<p style="font-size: small">
    &nbsp;</p>
                                    <p style="font-size: small">
                                        &nbsp;</p>
                                    <div class="clearfix" style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                        <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
                                            <span style="font-size: small">&nbsp;<a 
                                                href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/acute-diarrheal-disease.html"><span 
                                                id="act31">Acute Diarrheal Disease</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/allergy.html"><span 
                                                id="act16">Allergy</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/amebiasis.html"><span 
                                                id="act32">Amebiasis</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/appendicitis.html"><span 
                                                id="act17">Appendicitis</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/arthritis.html"><span 
                                                id="act18">Arthritis</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/asthma.html"><span 
                                                id="act19">Asthma</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/blindness.html"><span 
                                                id="act20">Blindness</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/blood-pressure.html"><span 
                                                id="act21">Blood Pressure</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/bronchitis.html"><span 
                                                id="act22">Bronchitis</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/brucellosis.html"><span 
                                                id="act33">Brucellosis</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/chicken-pox.html"><span 
                                                id="act34">Chicken Pox</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;</span><a 
                                                href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/chikungunya-fever.html"><span 
                                                id="act35"><span style="font-size: small">Chikungunya Fever</span></span></a><span 
                                                style="font-size: small"><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/cholera.html"><span 
            id="act36">Cholera</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/conjunctivitis.html"><span 
            id="act25">Conjunctivitis</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a 
            href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/computer-health-hazards.html"><span 
            id="act148">Computer Health Hazards</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/dengue.html"><span 
            id="act37">Dengue</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/diphtheria.html"><span 
            id="act38">Diphtheria</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a 
            href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/diagnostic-tests.html"><span 
            id="act149">Diagnostic Tests</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/dysentery.html"><span 
            id="act26">Dysentery</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/guinea-worm.html"><span 
            id="act27">Guinea Worm</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/hepatitis.html"><span 
            id="act39">Hepatitis</span></a><br />
                                            &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/hookworm.html"><span 
            id="act40">Hookworm</span></a>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/influenza.html"><span 
            id="act41">Influenza</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a 
            href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/irritable-bowel-syndrome.html"><span 
            id="act28">Irritable Bowel Syndrome</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a 
            href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/japanese-encephalitis.html"><span 
            id="act29">Japanese Encephalitis</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/leprosy.html"><span 
            id="act42">Leprosy</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/leptospirosis.html"><span 
            id="act43">Leptospirosis</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a 
            href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/lymphatic-filariasis.html"><span 
            id="act44">Lymphatic Filariasis</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/malaria.html"><span 
            id="act45">Malaria</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/measles.html"><span 
            id="act46">Measles</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/plague.html"><span 
            id="act30">Plague</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/poliomyelitis.html"><span 
            id="act47">Poliomyelitis</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/rabies.html"><span 
            id="act48">Rabies</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/rubella.html"><span 
            id="act49">Rubella</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/tetanus.html"><span 
            id="act50">Tetanus</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/tuberculosis.html"><span 
            id="act51">Tuberculosis</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/typhoid-fever.html"><span 
            id="act52">Typhoid Fever</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/viral-hepatitis.html"><span 
            id="act178">Viral Hepatitis</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/whooping-cough.html"><span 
            id="act53">Whooping Cough</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/yaws.html"><span 
            id="act54">Yaws</span></a><br />
        &#8226;&nbsp;</span><a 
            href="http://www.aarogya.com/conditions-and-diseases/yellow-fever.html"><span 
            id="act55"><span style="font-size: small">Yellow Fever</span></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
<p style="font-size: small">
    &nbsp;</p>


</asp:Content>
```

and i want to add this following code

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
img
{
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Image Transparency</h1>
<img src="klematis.jpg" width="150" height="113" alt="klematis"
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40" />

<img src="klematis2.jpg" width="150" height="113" alt="klematis"
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40" />
</body>
</html>
```

i dont want to affect the master page just the picture should get effected ,where to add this code ?

Comment: You mean you only want to apply to that particular image ?

Comment: appling the image with the effect

Comment: Did you have to give us the whole page? We truly don't need all the content here; that's _your_ business, not ours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't that as simple as

```
<asp:ImageButton Style="opacity:0.4; filter:alpha(opacity=40);" ID="ImageButton1" ... />
```

When you're ready to get fancier, add a rule to a CSS file and refer to it as

```
<asp:ImageButton CssClass="yourclassname" ID="ImageButton1" ... />
```

Either way, realize the effect won't appear in all browsers.